# getting records from date after 00:00:00 using BETWEEN in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I want to group the number of times a document has been viewed between/during certain days. The problem is when using BETWEEN in my query I get records with date, say between 01/12/2016 00:00:00 and 31/12/2016 00:00:00 which means all data from the 31/12/2016 is not displayed - I would like the query to get all data between 01/12/2016 00:00:00 and 31/12/2016 23:59:59. How do I do this?

```
    Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Query1 As String

    'getting values from the dropdowns
    Dim startdate As String = DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "/" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "/" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue
    Dim dtstart As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate.ToString)
    Dim enddate As String = DropDownList4.SelectedValue + "/" + DropDownList5.SelectedValue + "/" + DropDownList6.SelectedValue
    Dim dtend As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate.ToString)

    Query1 = "SELECT COUNT(Down.DocuID) AS CountDownload, Down.DocuID, CONVERT(CHAR(8), Down.DownloadDate, 121), Library.DocName FROM Down INNER JOIN Library ON Library.DocuID = Down.DocID WHERE (Down.DocuID = @DocID) AND (Down.DownloadDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND (Library.DocType <> @DocType) GROUP BY Down.DocuID, CONVERT(CHAR(8), Down.DownloadDate, 121), Library.DocName, Library.DocType"

    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = Query1 
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("DocID").DefaultValue = TextBox1.Text
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("startDate").DefaultValue = dtstart
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("endDate").DefaultValue = dtend

    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1
    GridView1.EmptyDataText = "No results"
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Down.DocuID) AS CountDownload, Down.DocuID, CONVERT(CHAR(8), Down.DownloadDate, 121), Library.DocName 
FROM Down 
INNER JOIN Library ON Library.DocuID = Down.DocID 
WHERE Down.DocuID = @DocID
AND Down.DownloadDate >= @startDate 
AND Down.DownloadDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @endDate) 
AND Library.DocType <> @DocType 
GROUP BY Down.DocuID, CONVERT(CHAR(8), Down.DownloadDate, 121), Library.DocName, Library.DocType"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use,

```
Down.DownloadDate >= @startDate AND Down.DownloadDate < DATEADD(DAY,1,@endDate)
```

Comment: Please accept this answer so that other people will know that the problem is solved (It's basically the same as mine, and I think Abdul needs the rep more then me)